# Use Promise to get the return data

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pull the data from realms and then process it using the native call. Once I get the processed data I further filter it in react native code and then give the return data. But till the time I complete all the activity the return parameter is already executed. Please have a look at the below code snippet:

```
async getArray() {
  realm = await this.getRealMObject();
  favoriteArray = realm.objects(constants.SCHEMA_SAVE);
  return favoriteArray;
}

async getLevel() {
  let low = 'false';
  let favoriteArray = await this.getAllArray();
  let getDetails = [];
  if (favoriteArray.length > 0) {
    for (var y in favoriteArray) {
      NativeModules.Get.GetAsyncTask(
        brd[0].toUpperCase(),
        strChk, '1',
        kResponse => {
          if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
            getDetails = kResponse;
          } else {
            getDetails = JSON.parse(kResponse);
          }
          for (let x = 0; x < getDetails.length; x++) {
            const strLevel = this.getPercentage(getDetails[x]);
            if (strLevel <= 20) {
              low = true;
            }
          }
        });
    }
  } else {
    low = false;
  }
  return low;
}
```

Above is the code snippet. So when I call `getlevel()` before the processing is finished I get the return `low` value.

How can I handle, this? I want the data to be processed and then get the return value.

Comment: You have to convert `NativeModules.Get.GetAsyncTask` into a promisified version. And then use that promisified version and `await`

Comment: Yes you are right t.niese. But I added one more step to it i.e. i create promise function for  NativeModules.Get.GetAsyncTask. And then one more promise for getLevel. Both of the promise i called using await method and it worked.